# In swift, I have a UIButton inside a UIView inside a UIStackView, and the button is not responding

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a UIButton, for which I have a touchUpInside IBAoutlet function call, and it is embedded inside a view, which is then embedded inside a stackview. I have User Interaction enabled for all three of of the stackview, the view and the button.

However, the touchUpInside function is not called when I click the button. Does anyone know if this has a solution?

Comment: You need to provide some more detail about your layout. Are you doing this via code or in Storyboard? What constraints have you setup? Have you used `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect your UI elements?

Comment: Sorry, I am using a storyboard, and I have not tried using that tool yet.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited context, I can only give a guess. Perhaps something is blocking the button such as another view on top of it? Sometimes the order of things in your storyboard file can make certain things not register touches.

Comment: Why the downvote? I said it was just a guess. Just wanted to throw something out there to help @vedjoshi1 think of something they might not have thought of just in case it pertained. The question didn't have a lot to go off..

Answer (score 0):

The container view for the button is likely shrined to a small size and thus it  and its subviews do not receive touches. Subviews are displayed because "Clip to bounds" is false by default for all views. So subviews are drawn even outside the bounds. The easiest way to check is to give a container view a background color.
If this is the case, then there are several ways to resolve the issue:

1. Set a reasonable constraints to the container. Stick to nearest neighbour boundaries, for example. Or set a minimum size.
2. Set a size for the container view.
3. If the container view is inside UIStackView you can set `Alignment` = `Fill`, (not `Center`) which will make the container view take the space suggested by UIStackView.